# Как задать отступы CSS

Tags: css

Имеется блок `DIV` с фиксированной шириной.
В него вложено 3 блока `DIV`.
Нужно отобразить их друг за другом и задать отступ между ними в 10px

Но так задать, чтобы по краям от родительского блока, крайних блоков, отступов не было. Отступы только между блоками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант:

html:

```
<div class="main">
  <div>раз</div>
  <div class="Two">два</div>
  <div>три</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.main div{
  display: block;
  float:left;
width:10px;/*ваши размеры*/
height:10px/*ваши размеры*/
}

.two{
  margin: 0px 10px;
  display: block;
}
```

---

Еще можно сделать с помощью ":first-child" и ":last-child"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/634D7/ что-то отступов не вижу

Comment: там Two - T - большая, необходим класс .Two

Comment: попробуйте для класса "Two"
следующее:

.main div.two{
  margin: 0px 20px;
  display: block;
}
 

и как рекомендовал предыдущий комментатор использовать одинаковые стили написания селекторов по строчным\заглавным буквам.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 320px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.main .inner {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.main .inner:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```